# Confidence interval for expected difference in Y for poisson multiple regression, changing one X variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, inference, delta-method

Suppose I have

$y_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\exp(\beta_0 + \beta x_{1,i} + \beta_2 x_{2,i}))$.

I run my regression, and I get estimates of $\beta$. I want to conduct inference on the following:

$E_{x_1}[y|x_1,{x_2 = 1}]-E_{x_1}[y|x_1,{x_2 = 0}] \sim  ? $

Note that the expectation is only over $x_1$.

I need the delta method right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct, self.